# How to convert a cURL command to http request in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, curl

I have this cURL command from paypal developers page:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
   -u "client_id:secret" \
   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

My question is, how can i convert that cURL command into a http request with angular?

Can you give me an example of how can i do that? Because i am new with angular and i need help with this..

Thanks!

Comment: That's very broad. Were you not able to find any learning resources about making HTTP requests from Angular?

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: @CrisoforoGaspar In the project that i will try to do it is the version 8.3.20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I would do is to figure out what you actually need to make the request. Looks like you have some auth headers that need to be passed and I'm assuming it's a `POST` request.

You could simplify it by using something like a [CURL to Http Request](https://reqbin.com/req/c-w7oitglz/convert-curl-to-http-request) tool to get it into a more familiar format.

TL;DR: Here you go:

```
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'Basic Y2xpZW50X2lkOnNlY3JldA=='
    });
    this.http.post('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', 'grant_type=client_credentials', { headers: headers });
```

`this.http` would be the reference to your injected `HttpClient`

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ffrget?file=src/app/app.component.ts). The request turns a 401 so I'm assuming the creds are invalid.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you need an secret key from your paypal account to do it, but it works for me because i have that, so i have to include result of the conversion into the http header?

Comment: Yea, if that gives you an auth token, you want to replace your `Authorization` header with that token in subsequent API calls.